# .Net X509KeyStore and certmgr.msc mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

So basically I have this bit of code:

```
var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (var certificate in x509Store.Certificates)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(certificate.SubjectName.Name);
}
```

Pretty simple right? Get the list of root certificates for the "Current User" and print them to the console. There is no way this couldn't work, right?

Well, that's what I thought too. Running this code dumps a list of 43 certificates, but if I run certmgr.msc the current user actually has 52 certificates installed in the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" store. So I'm 9 certificates short, one of which is the one I actually need. What am I missing?

Comment: Are missing certificates invalid?

Comment: Define "invalid". The one I need to feth works fine when served from Ruby (Webbrick) or Java(Jetty). If I change it to StoreName.Disallowed I don't get it there either.

Comment: Expired, recalled, etc... Take a look at `X509Certificate2Collection.Find` method, there's parameter `validOnly`. I'm assuming, that by default `X509Certificate2Collection` being filled with valid certificates only. Try to find certificate you need using `x509Store.Certificates.Find(someFindType, someFindValue, false)`.

Comment: It seems invalid = "Does not contain a private key". Strange.